# How do I get started with ROS2 on a mac?

Tags: ros2, mac

There seems to be several options for using ROS2 on a mac, but I'm not sure which is easiest for a beginner:

- Just use linux in VirtualBox.
- Install Docker and use a Docker Image. Seems like a great idea considering the complexity of installation... and ROS images can be found on DockerHub, but the pull command generates errors about the latest package not being there.
- Build it using Xcode and Brew - but I have to disable the security settings??? What? Why??? I really don't like the idea of putting my main computer in a compromised state and booting into recovery...

So what is the best option?
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! 
The official documentation may help: https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Installation/Alternatives/macOS-Development-Setup.html

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* @Benice, but I'm afraid that questions which ask about the Pros/cons or Advantages/disadvantages are effectively opinion polls, which are [discouraged on stack exchange](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/). We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of advantages & disadvantages for different options are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: Linux in Fusion VM is much easier to maintain and understand.  ROS in Docker is always making me rebuild with a missing package, or solving display issues.

Comment: Helpful, thank you.